# Login required in backend after setting is_secure to false [Symfony]

Tags: php, security, symfony1, backend

I'm honestly going crazy with symfony. I had installed the sfDoctrineGuardUser plugin but since it was giving an error that i couldn't solve (Unknown method SfGuardUserTable::retrieveByUsername) I uninstalled it. In the file backend/config/security.yml I have currently set the option for is_secure to false.

```
default:
  is_secure: false;
```

BUT when I access backend_dev.php it still says:

Login Required
This page is not public.

I've deleted all references to sfGuardPlugin, have no other is_secure property set in inner modules, and I have cleaned the cache about 10000000 times.

PLEASE HELP ME!

Comment: Check symfony's log to see what and where redirects to the secure page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the semicolon.
The right setting is:

```
default:
  is_secure: false
```

Finally clear your cache for production environment.

Answer (score 0):

If you cleared cache and you are still being asked to login, you may want to check to see if you enabled the `is_secure` setting at the module level. Symfony allows for app level and module level secure access, so if your app config is set to `is_secure: false`, your module config may still be `is_secure: true`.